# Inside HVAC furnace, zero ohm between R wire and W wire, is that normal?

Tags: hvac, repair, furnace

I have a Lennox system (G27M series). The transformer has a 3amp breaker. It trips time when the R wire and W wire are connected (heat is on).

To find out where the circuit is short, I attempted to measure the resistance between R wire and W wire, and found the reading is zero ohm (thermostat was taken off and furnace was unplugged). 
Is that normal? Is it a sign that the control board is broken?

[image]

Comment: If you remove the W wire from the control board terminal and recheck the resistance of the thermostat R and W wires, is it still 0 ohms?

Comment: Where did you measure the wires?  Coming out of the wall at the thermostat, inside the air handler?  Where?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I measured the resistance at the control board inside the furnace.

Comment: @Jeff I will check that when I am back home. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff yes, it is still o ohms. I also tried to measure resistance of the control board alone (disconnect the jack plug to heat controls), then resistance is about ~500 ohm between R wire and W wire; about ~1700 ohm between R wire and Y wire. Does this indicate something wrong with the control board?

Comment: @zhanxw maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but 0 ohms across two different thermostat wires that aren't connected to anything means there is a short in the wires. The resistance between the control board terminals sounds about normal.

Comment: @Jeff sorry for that. The 0 ohms between R and W happened when the 9 pin jack plug (J58 in the schematic diagram) was plugged in and all wires  from the control board to thermostat were disconnected.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your comments on the resistance between control board terminals. I will check the 9 pin jack plugs (J58). That is the wire to primary limit, rollout switch, pressure switch and gas valve. I will look for voltage shorts there.

Comment: @Jeff I found the short is caused by the primary limit. I will replace it and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff the problem is that the secondary limit switch (installed inside the blower) is connected to the ground and caused the shortage. Thanks.